# EXC_BAD_ACCESS in different places but all on NSUSERDEFAULTS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsuserdefaults

I am constantly getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error in multiple places but always on the nsuserdefaults below is the places were it keeps erroring.

```
    //Get results
NSString *currentYes = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"yes"];
NSString *currentNo = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"no"];
```

And again here:

```
- (IBAction)VoteQ1:(id)sender
{
    //Save question 1 to device
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:@"Q1" forKey:@"questionnumber"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[self.Question1 objectAtIndex:0] forKey:@"Question"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[self.Question1 objectAtIndex:1] forKey:@"yes"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[self.Question1 objectAtIndex:2]forKey:@"no"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[self.Question1 objectAtIndex:3] forKey:@"start"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[self.Question1 objectAtIndex:4] forKey:@"end"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];


    FlipViewController *controller = [[FlipViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FlipView" bundle:nil];
        controller.delegate = self;

        controller.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
        [self presentModalViewController:controller animated:YES];

        [controller release];
}
```

i also have `(IBAction)VoteQ2:(id)sender` and `(IBAction)VoteQ3:(id)sender` which are the same as above but self.question1 is like question 2 or 3.

The error comes when i click another ibaction after clicking and completing the flip view.

Please help i believe it is something to do with nsuserdefaults not releasing it self

Thanks

Comment: It would help if you pointed out the exact lines where the errors are occurring.  Also, based on what you've described, I don't think the cause of the error is in the code segments you posted.  It would be useful to see any areas of code where you retain or release the NSUserDefaults object (which you should never have to do btw).

Comment: errors on any standard user defaults line

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It might be a casting problem.  You are setting an object

```
setObject:[self.Question1 objectAtIndex:1]
```

but fetching it into an NSString:

```
stringForKey:@"yes"
```

**Assuming** your objects in Question1 array are NSString objects, try this:

```
NSString *currentYes = (NSString *)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"yes"];
```

Answer (score 0):

These things are usually due to using a pointer to an expired object. You can run with zombies enabled to help isolate.

Look at the stack back track to isolate the line on which its occurring and report back.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you NSArray object, self.Question1, is out of bounds. 
i.e there are only 2 objects inside self.Question1 but you are trying to get objectAtIndex 4.

Comment: inside question 1 is actually 5 objects